# Tableview records keep repeating and overlapping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
if (cell == nil) {    
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
}   
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,11,320,40)];
    label.text = [animalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:label];
```

In the `animalArray` i have the following items,

```
Lion, Dog, Cat, Zebra, Donkey, Monkey...
```

The problem is;

1.) When i add the label inside the `if (cell == nil) {` condition i see repeated records. like L`ion, Dog, Cat, Zebra` and then again `Lion` as i scroll down.

2.) When i add it outside the `if (cell == nil) {` the records overlap as i scroll.

I understand that this is because the cell is reusing its self, and i am creating a Label each time (so it gets overlapped). I don't know how to fix this issue programatically. Can someone please help me.

EDIT:

I have just displayed 1 label here. but i have more than one label to display. and also some UIComponants.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the problem persist when you use `[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I writing this code without checking syntax:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
if (cell == nil) {    
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,11,320,40)];
label.tag = 556;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; 
}   
UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:556];
    cellLabel.text = [animalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: That's a lot of Labels. Don't you think there might be a better approach than this?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. There is only one UILabel added per cell. Then once the cell dequeues, I'm getting a reference to that existing UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to add label to your table cell. it already has cell.textLabel.text=@"some string".
replace this part:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,11,320,40)];
label.text = [animalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell addSubview:label];
```

with this:
    cell.textLabel.text=[animalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: I have just displayed 1 label here. but i have more than one label to display. and also some UIComponants.

Comment: okay now i know what you want. if you use storyboard choose custom for your cell with labels und images drag and drop it. then assign the class with your own class which contains iboutlets.

Comment: Well. i am not using storyboard. I am creating every UI component by code.

Comment: and dont forget to control drag from cell to the labels and images and choose the right outlet

Comment: Well, i am not going to use Storyboard in this project. :( I have to create it for both ios 4 and 5. So have to find another solution it seems

Comment: okay then i cant help since i started with ios 5 with storyboard. i just had the same situation. its pretty simple with storyboard. it took me 5 mins. i think in ur case create the class of type uitableviewcel with outlets and connect it with xib file containing the labels and other uicompoenents then assign /instantiate and add it to your table.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be subclassing UITableViewCell and adding all labels. That way you need to set labels' text properties outside of the
`if (cell == nil){...}` 
block.

Answer (score -2):

use this by removing if(cell == nil)

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,11,320,40)];
label.text = [animalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell addSubview:label];
[label release];
```

Comment: Okay, can you tell me the purpose of having that if statement ?

Comment: No, you need to do that conditional check.  The whole purpose of using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and the conditional check is to reuse table cells and conserve memory.  If there are a lot of items in the array and the user scrolls through them, the memory due to all the newly allocated uitableview cells will grow and potentially cause the system to kill the app.

Comment: So i have loads of items in my array to be displayed in the table. So i guess i will have to reuse the table (meaning i have to use the condition check). Can you tell me how to do this programatically ?